# How to reinstall deloyment manager after server die

Tags: websphere

I have installed WebSphere on three boxes (box1, box2, box3) with AppSvr01 and AppSvr02 federate to Dmgr

Box1 (Dmgr, Cell ): Deployment Manager, Cell

Box2 (node agent) AppSvr01

Box3 (node agent) AppSvr02

Can I create a new Deployment Manager and federate AppSvr01, AppSvr02 if Box1 died.

Answer (score 0):

Node can be only member of single deployment manager.
If you lost completely Box1 and dont have backup of the dmgr profile, you will have to recreate dmgr and then refederate nodes.

By refederate I mean that nodes would have to be federated again.

Things to consider:

- when you will run removeNode, then all the node configuration will be revert back to the state before federation (possibly empty node)

If this is not what you want, you could use `wsadmin` and use task  `AdminTask.extractConfigProperties` to export node configuration, and then try to reapply it after node will be federated again.

You have to be aware that since dmgr is not available some of the configuration data will not be available.

The easiest would be to recover somehow Dmgr config from backup, (that's why it is quite important to at least run backupConfig on dmgr from time to time and store it in safe place), but I assume you dont have one ;-).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please share detail steps backupConfig and restoreConfig also how to refederate Node to new deployment manager.

Comment: Thank you so much, but could you please also share how to re-federate the Node to new deployment manager.